# Regex match until empty line but leave the last sentence in

Tags: regex

I can select all with this `FOR\sYOU.*?(?:\r*\n){2}` but how can I separate the last sentence? The number of lines from FOR YOU until the last line before the empty line may vary.

I want this block of text:

```
FOR YOU
wool suit jacket
26 Cute Winter Date Night Outfits for Men and Women
Dresses, pants, shirts and skirts sure to bring the heat to your cold-weather date night.
Purple wedding dresses
24 Purple Wedding Dresses for the High-Fashion Bride
Shake up your ceremony with a jaw-dropping purple gown
Bride and groom elope in New York City.
30 Best Elopement Dresses for 2023
Plus, what to know before buying.
Take a Trip to the Tailor

New paragraph
```

To be replaced by this:

```
Take a Trip to the Tailor
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear, do you want to get just last line? Or do you want a way to separate this last line? If first - something like `([^\n]+)(?:\r*\n){2}` should be good start, if second - `FOR\sYOU.*?\n([^\n]+)(?:\r*\n){2}`, your last line will be in first group.

Comment: @markalex Thank you! I meant the second option where I want to separate the last line. If you could post your comment as an answer I will accept it as an answer. And also it would be nice if you could explain what does what in the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like `FOR\sYOU.*?\n([^\n]+)(?:\r*\n){2}`.

Last line will be in first group.

A word of **caution**: this regexp assumes, that empty line doesn't immediately follows line `FOR YOU`